# How to load existing TableViewController on click of button iOS5

Tags: ios5, uiview, uitableview, pushviewcontroller, viewdidload

I created UIExamsTVC using storyboards.

Once cell is clicked, it takes me to UITestVC.

UITestVC has 10 questions, When I get to the last question #10, there I have a "Done" button. I would like to go back to the original UIExamsTVC once the 'Done' button Clicked.

In: UITestVC.m

```
 #import UIExamsTVC.h
 (on button click)
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:UIExamsTVC animated:NO];
```

- Compile error - Unexpected Interface name

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go **back** then you don't want to push anything new...that's just adds to the existing stack.  If you got to the `UITestVC` through a push, you want a "pop" in order to go back.  If you got there by presenting it modally, you want to "dismiss" it.

(What your actual error is telling you is that you can't use the name of a class when the method you're calling wants a reference to an object.)